# How to remove the "Contents" header

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing my PhD thesis in LaTeX and I'm trying to get it to match uni standards.

My headings need to be in two lines, even the Table of Content. I managed to include this but can't get rid of the "Contents" header automatically created by using `ToC`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\section*{Table of Contents} %heading I do want

\tableofcontents %heading I don't want or want to change to "Table of Contents"
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code of what you tried? The second thing you tried has an incomplete syntax anyway:  `\renewcommand` wants a second argument, the new name of the table of contents.

Comment: I think you are looking for `\contentsname`. Try `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}`

Comment: I tried Michael's suggestion... not working.

Comment: Bernard, what do you need for a compilable code? I have tons of use package commands in the beginning and all the chapters in separate files so not sure what you need.

Comment: @AlexandraPfeiffer: The problem is that you have tons of packages there -- and the more packages you load the more complications and combinations of code, sometimes amending, sometimes contradicting pile up -- without seeing the compilable code it is very hard to provide a solution

Comment: @Bernard: It seems to be a `titlesec` usage (just a guess by `\titlerule`), you are one of our `titlesec` gurus here, perhaps you have an idea

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. As fas as I'm aware, the \titlerule comment only generates the lines for the top header and doesn't impact what \tableofcontents does - correct me if I'm wrong. I'll try to include a compilable code in the initial question.

Comment: We  simply need to know the documentclass, which packages are loaded — some might interact with the result. We're not the oracle at Delphi, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `article` class? It has no chapters.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}` perhaps and omitting the `\titlerule` commands, if that is all you want what the `\section*{Table of Contents}` should provide?

Comment: Christian, your suggestion doesn't work. Bernard, is there a way I can upload the .tex file here so you can have a look at the `\usepackage` commands? I got the file of a friend and there are so many packages and I don't even know what some of them are for.

Comment: @AlexandraPfeiffer: Why does `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}` not work? When I use that in your minimal code it works.

Comment: @Werner: Most likely the `\renewcommand{\contentsname}` collides with `titlesec` and other of the tons of packages ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A solution (will be removed later on) without extra packages (apart from the dummy `blindtext` generator), by 'injecting' a `\rule` command before and after the `\section*` command, assuming `article` class, as in the OP and redefinition of `\contentsname`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\newlength{\tocheaderrulewidth}
\setlength{\tocheaderrulewidth}{2pt}

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \begingroup
  \parindent=0em
  \rule{\linewidth}{\tocheaderrulewidth}% Rule drawing
  \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
   \rule{\linewidth}{\tocheaderrulewidth}
   \endgroup

  \@starttoc{toc}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents %heading I don't want or want to change to "Table of Contents"
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll work this into the code tomorrow, hopefully it works. If not, I'll ask for help again! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `titlesec + titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, english]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of contents}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\thispagestyle{empty}\bfseries\Large\filcenter}{\thechapter. }{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\thispagestyle{empty}\bfseries\Large\titlerule[1pt]\bigskip\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\MakeUppercase}[\medskip{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0em] %
{\bigskip\bfseries\large}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace \MakeUppercase}%\thecontentslabel
{\centerline}
{\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents %heading I don't want or want to change to "Table of Contents"
\chapter{Looking-Glass House}
\chapter{The Garden of Live Flowers}
\chapter{Looking-Glass Insects}
\chapter{Tweedledum and Tweedledee}
\chapter{Wool and Water}
\chapter{Humpty Dumpty}
\chapter{The Lion and the Unicorn}
\chapter{‘It’s my own Invention’}
\chapter{Queen Alice}
\chapter{Shaking}
\chapter{Waking}
\chapter{Which Dreamed it?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard! This is really helpful. As I'm new to LaTex I'm still amazed by the endless opportunities and by how helpful the community is :)